# Invalid login attempt in login with some users

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-5, asp.net-identity, asp.net-identity-2

I have a random error in login action. It is an application with MVC 5.2 and AspNet.Identity 2.

When some user try login `SignInStatus.Failure` error occurs in:

```
SignInStatus result = await 
        SignInManager.PasswordSignInAsync(
            model.Email, 
            model.Password, 
            model.RememberMe, shouldLockout: false);
```

This happens randomly with users, if a user connects fine, then it may fail to connect.

Registration done correctly, then this may or may not connect. is not asking for confirmation of the account.

The first time I probe the system worked correctly, the next day I started this local problem or on the server.

Comment: I have the same problem, have you had any luck getting it to work?

Comment: Hi @Repo, I did two changes at the moment works. I first changed to "PasswordSignIn" (no async), and second I´m now asking for confirmation via email. 
Unfortunately I do not know if this is the best solution, but for now it works for me.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

SignInManager.PasswordSignInAsync requires Username and Password not an Email and Password so if you have Username same as Email it will work with you else it won't work.

here is the signature of the PasswordSignInAsync [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt173779(v=vs.108).aspx)

```
public virtual Task<SignInStatus> PasswordSignInAsync(
    string userName,
    string password,
    bool isPersistent,
    bool shouldLockout 
)
```

to allow SignIn using Email while having different Username, modify you AccountController.Login to the following

```
User user = null;
using (DbContext db = new DbContext())
{
     user = db.Users.Single(u => u.Email.Equals(model.Email));    
}
if (user != null)
{
     var result = SignInManager.PasswordSignInAsync(user.UserName, model.Password, model.RememberMe, shouldLockout: false);

     switch (result)
     {
          case SignInStatus.Success:
               return RedirectToLocal(returnUrl);
          case SignInStatus.LockedOut:
               return View("Lockout");
          case SignInStatus.RequiresVerification:
               return RedirectToAction("SendCode", new {ReturnUrl = returnUrl, RememberMe = model.RememberMe});
          case SignInStatus.Failure:
          default:
               ModelState.AddModelError("", "Invalid login attempt.");
               return View(model);
      }
}
else
{
      //Handle User not found
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You are passing the EMAIL instead of the required UserName or User. It's better to query the user by awaiting _userManager.FindByEmailAsync(Input.Email). Then pass this user to the PasswordSignInAsync task. Like this:

```
var user = await _userManager.FindByEmailAsync(Input.Email);
var result = await _signInManager.PasswordSignInAsync(user, Input.Password, Input.RememberMe, lockoutOnFailure: false);
```